# Fetch list of keyword XML with metadata

Tags: 2011, core-service, taxonomy

I am trying to fetch list of keywords under a particular keyword using ChildKeywordsFilterData. When i use GetListXml() method i am able to fetch the list of keywords in XML format. I want to include the metadata of the child keywords in the XML.
Is there a way to fetch keywords list which includes metadata also.

Answer (score 2):

To fetch the Metadata you need to first create an object for any item in Tridion through core services. If you really want to get an xml having metadata included then try to create one.
 
1> loop through all your keywords what you got after using GetListXml(), create `keywordData`.
2> include metadata using `keywordData.Metadata` in your new xml.